# How can I specify additional clang options for Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, compiler-construction, clang

I have created my custom `clang` plugin with help of [this tutorial](http://kevinaboos.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/clang-tutorial-part-iii-plugin-example/)
and I want to run it automatically on my Xcode iOS project.

I need to run following additional commands on `clang`,

```
-Xclang -load \
-Xclang ~/static_analysis/llvm/Debug+Asserts/lib/libPluginExample.so \
-Xclang -plugin -Xclang -example-plugin \
```

I would like to save all other commands generated by Xcode, because it is difficult to create and pass those commands for every Xcode project. That is the reason why I choose to use `clang` plugin but not `clang` tool.

How can I do achieve this?

Or how can I extract compiler flags generated by xcode aoutomtically, to use them in clang tool? (becouse, for correct using tool I need to specify all include directories, and all sources, and all frameworks)

**Update:**

I have added thous commands in Project

> Settings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources (double click on source)

,
but in compile time there is error (plugin is standard example libPrintFunctionNames.dylib from clang sources):

> error: unable to load plugin
>   '/Users/...llvm/Debug+Asserts/lib/libPrintFunctionNames.dylib':
>   'dlopen(/Users/.../llvm/Debug+Asserts/lib/libPrintFunctionNames.dylib,
>   9): Symbol not found:
>   __ZN5clang11ASTConsumer21HandleInterestingDeclENS_12DeclGroupRefE   Referenced from:
>   /Users/.../llvm/Debug+Asserts/lib/libPrintFunctionNames.dylib
>   Expected in: flat namespace  in
>   /Users/.../llvm/Debug+Asserts/lib/libPrintFunctionNames.dylib'
>   Command /Applications/Xcode
>   2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1

I have tried to use `libPrintFunctionNames.a` instead of `libPrintFunctionNames.dylib`, but it doe not help.

Maybe the cause is that I built my plugin on separated source files of llvm and clang, and in xcode I use other version of clang. I will check that.

Answer (score 6):

I would specify additional Clang options in build option OTHER_CFLAGS.  You can do so in

```
target/project Build Settings -> Apple LLVM 5.0 - Custom Compiler Flags -> Other C Flags
```

Or you can specify OTHER_CFLAGS for `xcodebuild`, for example,

```
xcodebuild -scheme SampleProject build OTHER_CFLAGS="-Xclang -load -Xclang /path/to/libPrintFunctionNames.dylib -Xclang -plugin -Xclang print-fns"
```

`xcodebuild` is convenient when you don't want to maintain 2 targets which differ only in OTHER_CFLAGS.

But you're right, it looks like you really need to link against the same libraries as clang itself is linked.  At least I've downloaded Clang+LLVM 3.3 binaries from http://llvm.org/releases/download.html , built the plugin with downloaded libraries and it works with clang from http://llvm.org, but doesn't work with clang from Xcode - I encounter the following error:

```
error: unable to find plugin 'print-fns'
```

I've created Xcode workspace which builds Clang plugin and shows how you can try to use it with default iOS application.  You can find it at https://github.com/vsapsai/ClangPluginExample

Comment: I've faced the same issue, but managed to solve via small Xcode hack.

http://railsware.com/blog/2014/02/28/creation-and-using-clang-plugin-with-xcode/ 
Here is more detailed explanation about how to make it work with Xcode.

Comment: Good point, @AlexDenisov. Another way to force Xcode to use custom compiler is via xcodebuild. The command looks like xcodebuild [..some arguments..] CC=/path/to/custom/clang CXX=/path/to/custom/clang